# remove extra junk characters from external files

Tags: beautifulsoup

This code extract the marathi text from my blog correctly. I appreciate how easy it is using beautiful soup and regular expression.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, re

url = "http://shabdasampada.blogspot.com/2020/01/blog-post_29.html"

headers = requests.utils.default_headers()
req = requests.get(url, headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
text = soup.get_text()

p = re.compile(r'[^\u0900-\u097F\n]')
for line in text.splitlines():
    cleaned = p.sub(' ', line)
    if cleaned.strip():
        print(cleaned)
```

But I can see some junk characters in the last few lines. like this...

> "ल              क म       ळव                                          ल              क म       ळव"

How do I remove those lines?

---

Update:

My code returns this:

> नाबर की नंबर  स्वभाषेत टंकलेखन साहाय्य २९ जानेवारी  २०२० नाबर की
>   नंबर  गुगलने मशीन लर्निंगचा वापर करून सर्च रिझल्ट दाखवायला सुरुवात
>   केली  त्याला आता फार नाही पण एक दोनच महिने झाले असतील  काही बाबतीत
>   रिझल्टमध्ये सुधारणा झाली असली तरी इतर बऱ्याच बाबतीत आणि विशेषतः
>   देवनागरी सर्चची क्वालिटी घसरलेली दिसते   आज मी  मंगेश नाबर  या
>   व्यक्तीची माहिती गुगलून पाहिली तर  मंगेश  आणि  नंबर   हे दोन शब्द
>   असलेली पाने पहिल्या पानावर दिसत आहेत  बहुतेक गुगलने  नाबर  या शब्दाला
>   बदलून  नंबर  केले असावे  द्वारा पोस्ट केलेले येथे १० ०४ म पू  लेबल  हे
>   राम  कोणत्याही टिप्पण् या नाहीत  टिप्पणी पोस्ट करा नवीनतम पोस्ट थोडे
>   जुने पोस्ट मुख्यपृष्ठ याची सदस्यता घ्या  टिप्पणी पोस्ट करा
>   ब्लॉग संग्रहण मनोगताचा स्पेल चेकर बसलय की बसलंय  नाबर की नंबर 
>   स्पर्धापरीक्षेचा खरा धोका माझ्याबद्दल माझे पूर्ण प्रोफाइल पहा 
>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       ल              क म       ळव                                          ल
>   क म       ळव
>   वर श       अर कर                                           ह       ब
>   ल       गकर                                               ह       ब
>   ल       गकर
>   वर श       अर कर
>   वर श       अर कर                                            ईम       ल
>   ईम       ल
>   अध       क व       च
>   न       बर क        न       बर
>   न       बर क        न       बर
>   स       प       दन                             ल              क क
>   ल       पब       र       डवर क       प        क       ल
>   ठ       क आह                       ल              क प       स       ट
>   कर
>   न       बर क        न       बर                     ग       गलन
>   मश       न लर       न              गच        व       पर कर       न सर 
>   च र       झल       ट द       खव       यल        स       र       व
>   त क       ल         त       य       ल        आत        फ       र न
>   ह        पण एक द       नच मह       न        झ       ल        असत
>   ल
>
> ```
>                                                                                                                                                                                       ल       ड ह       त आह
> ```

My Question is that the following part is not seen anywhere on the page. I will like to know it's origin.

> क म       ळव                                          ल              क
>   म       ळव
>   वर श       अर कर                                           ह       ब
>   ल       गकर                                               ह       ब
>   ल       गकर
>   वर श       अर कर
>   वर श       अर कर                                            ईम       ल
>   ईम       ल
>   अध       क व       च
>   न       बर क        न       बर
>   न       बर क        न       बर
>   स       प       दन                             ल              क क
>   ल       पब       र       डवर क       प        क       ल
>   ठ       क आह                       ल              क प       स       ट
>   कर
>   न       बर क        न       बर                     ग       गलन
>   मश       न लर       न              गच        व       पर कर       न सर 
>   च र       झल       ट द       खव       यल        स       र       व
>   त क       ल         त       य       ल        आत        फ       र न
>   ह        पण एक द       नच मह       न        झ       ल        असत
>   ल
>
> ```
>                                                                                                                                                                                       ल       ड ह       त आह
> ```

---

Update 2:

I forgot to remove javascript!

```
for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
    script.decompose()
text = soup.get_text()
```

Comment: can you tell which part of the text in the blog you want exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data you are getting is coming from the blog only so since you are not specifying exactly what you want you are getting everything.

Assuming you only want

[image]

Then you have to specify to beautiful soup exactly this part and nothing more.

Your code is reading everything from that page :

output:

```
                           नाबर की नंबर 
स्वभाषेत टंकलेखन साहाय्य
२९ जानेवारी  २०२०
नाबर की नंबर 
गुगलने मशीन लर्निंगचा वापर करून सर्च रिझल्ट दाखवायला सुरुवात केली  त्याला आता फार नाही पण एक दोनच महिने झाले असतील 
काही बाबतीत रिझल्टमध्ये सुधारणा झाली असली तरी इतर बऱ्याच बाबतीत आणि विशेषतः देवनागरी सर्चची क्वालिटी घसरलेली दिसते   आज मी  मंगेश नाबर  या व्यक्तीची माहिती गुगलून पाहिली तर  मंगेश  आणि  नंबर   हे दोन शब्द असलेली पाने पहिल्या पानावर दिसत आहेत  बहुतेक गुगलने  नाबर  या शब्दाला बदलून  नंबर  केले असावे 
द्वारा पोस्ट केलेले
येथे
१० ०४ म पू 
लेबल 
हे राम 
कोणत्याही टिप्पण् या नाहीत 
टिप्पणी पोस्ट करा
नवीनतम पोस्ट
थोडे जुने पोस्ट
मुख्यपृष्ठ
याची सदस्यता घ्या 
टिप्पणी पोस्ट करा       
ब्लॉग संग्रहण
मनोगताचा स्पेल चेकर
बसलय की बसलंय 
नाबर की नंबर 
स्पर्धापरीक्षेचा खरा धोका
माझ्याबद्दल
माझे पूर्ण प्रोफाइल पहा 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    ल              क म       ळव                                          ल              क म       ळव                                                                                           वर श       अर कर                                           ह       ब       ल       गकर                                               ह       ब       ल       गकर                                                                                             वर श       अर कर                                                                                                     वर श       अर कर                                            ईम       ल                                    ईम       ल                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     अध       क व       च                                                                            न       बर क        न       बर                                              न       बर क        न       बर                                                                                                                                           स       प       दन                             ल              क क       ल       पब       र       डवर क       प        क       ल                  ठ       क आह                       ल              क प       स       ट कर                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     न       बर क        न       बर                     ग       गलन        मश       न लर       न              गच        व       पर कर       न सर       च र       झल       ट द       खव       यल        स       र       व       त क       ल         त       य       ल        आत        फ       र न       ह        पण एक द       नच मह       न        झ       ल        असत       ल                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                          ल       ड ह       त आह
```

But with:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, re

url = "http://shabdasampada.blogspot.com/2020/01/blog-post_29.html"

headers = requests.utils.default_headers()
req = requests.get(url, headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')

h=soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':"post hentry uncustomized-post-template"})[0]

text = h.get_text()

p = re.compile(r'[^\u0900-\u097F\n]')
for line in text.splitlines():
    cleaned = p.sub(' ', line)
    if cleaned.strip():
        print(cleaned)
```

output will be:

```
नाबर की नंबर 
गुगलने मशीन लर्निंगचा वापर करून सर्च रिझल्ट दाखवायला सुरुवात केली  त्याला आता फार नाही पण एक दोनच महिने झाले असतील 
काही बाबतीत रिझल्टमध्ये सुधारणा झाली असली तरी इतर बऱ्याच बाबतीत आणि विशेषतः देवनागरी सर्चची क्वालिटी घसरलेली दिसते   आज मी  मंगेश नाबर  या व्यक्तीची माहिती गुगलून पाहिली तर  मंगेश  आणि  नंबर   हे दोन शब्द असलेली पाने पहिल्या पानावर दिसत आहेत  बहुतेक गुगलने  नाबर  या शब्दाला बदलून  नंबर  केले असावे 
द्वारा पोस्ट केलेले
येथे
१० ०४ म पू 
लेबल 
हे राम
```

you can see that I specified the div which has the data you need

```
h=soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':"post hentry uncustomized-post-template"})[0]
```

to check this you will have to check the html of the webpage to know exactly where the data you want is. You can use Ctrl+Shift+i in chrome for that.

I would suggest you look through [this](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/web-scraping-with-beautiful-soup) post for more info

**For your last question**

The junk data that you are seeing is coming from your website only.

BeautifulSoup gets the data from the page source and since you have not mentioned any condition to tell it what data you want you will get all of it..
To understand where your junk data is coming from, look at the page source of your 
website.

if you look at the page source you will find this junk at the end of the html code.

[image]

This is the source of all that junk that you see in your output.

If you make this change:
In place of '`cleaned`' print '`line`'

```
p = re.compile(r'[^\u0900-\u097F\n]')
for line in text.splitlines():
    cleaned = p.sub(' ', line)
    if cleaned.strip():
        print(line)
```

you will see a lot of junk data in the end this way .. that junk data is actually present in your page's source code and in that code since you were filtering only for a specific set of characters ,you only saw those

Comment: Upvoted, but I have one more doubt. Can you run my code on this blog post http://pashanbhed.blogspot.com and let me know why do I see the last 8 lines even if they are not there in source code? Are there any templates for scrapping blogger blog posts?

Comment: I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the 'junk' symbols are inside the filter interval that you defined in `re.compile` (0x900 -0x97F) :

```
print ([hex(ord(s)) for s in "लकमळवलकमळव"])
>> ['0x932', '0x915', '0x92e', '0x933', '0x935', '0x932', '0x915', '0x92e', '0x933', '0x935']
```

You may want to add another filter or adjust the `re.compile` arguments...